# convert circuit to nor only gates

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, applications

[image]for an assignment I need to convert a circuit to NOR gates only circuit.

(A+B)C + D

I know that morgan's theorem states:

(a) (A+B)'=A'B' 
(b) (AB)'=A'+B'

I've seen online how to convert some gates to nor gates, for example the NOT gate to a NOR gate with the input tied together.. 
But I am not able to apply the morgan's theorem on my circuit has there are 4 inputs. 
Any hints?

thanks!

Comment: HINT: (A+B)C=E, then use E+D

Comment: But I suppose I need to solve each one..
So I did that:

(A'+C')' + (B' + C')' + D

because I think AC + BC + D

so I've transformed the first two AND in NOR..
but now I would need to make the two OR two NOR (and not NAND)..

So I started with

(((A'+C')')' + (B'+C')')' )' + D

but it looks a bit crazy..
I would then proceed further making the last not with D in the same way..
is that correct?
I will need to draw the circuit as well :/

Comment: Added tag (boolean-algebra), which is what mathematicians call this sort of problem.  By "logic" they often mean something else.

Comment: HINT: use the following equivalences: PQ=(P↓P)↓(Q↓Q), P+Q=(P↓Q)↓(P↓Q), where ↓ denotes Logic NOR. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Introduction.2C_elimination.2C_and_equivalencies

Comment: Nice! You've used some NOR gats connected as NOT gates. You might post your circuit as an answer and accept it to avoid having questions not accepted. Just a comment on the number of brackets: the second last gate should be `(P+(C′+(((A+B)′)′)′)′)′` and the last one `((P+(C′+(((A+B)′)′)′)′)′)′`. In the circuit the input `P` is the variable `D` in the question body.

Comment: Which software did you use to produce the drawing?

Comment: thanks yes I did a mistake writing the comment.. I am using a circuit simulator to check if the result was correct and I took a screenshot.. It is called Logic Circuit Designer.. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Just an information: to notify somebody of a comment of yours posted here you should type @ before her/his name.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

here the circuit I have been able to write.. P is instead of D

Comment: +1, It seems everything is right. I've deleted my answer, because yours is shorter and thus better. You may consider accepting your own answer or waiting for another answer.